# Is there a connection between Invoice and Order?

Tags: order

We're working on a Salesforce integration in our product and the requirement if we search for specific order with order Id from a specific account via the API it should return order details, product related to that details and **Invoice Details**.

While I can get order and product details because product table has `OrderId` association from where I can create join query to merge the response but I don't see any co-relation between orders and invoice anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Invoice` object has lookup to `Order` or `Order Summary` called `ReferenceEntityId`. This is the Id of the order or order summary that created the invoice.

This is a polymorphic relationship, which means that the field can look up to different types of object. (Normally lookups only lookup to one type)

You can consult the *Object Reference for the Salesforce Platform* documentation for details on all fields available on standard objects in Salesforce. Here is the page for Invoice: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_invoice.htm